# Getting a value from a change function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this is probably really simple, but I apparently just cant think of how to do this. I've never had a need to do this before.

I have a value that stays the same unless a radio button is clicked and changes it. I then need to pass that value into a click function so I can call that class. Does that make sense?

I'm setting the variable at the top of the page like so...

```
var sortDate = 'revRec';
```

and then I'm running a change function to grab the value of the input if it changes

```
$("input[name='sortField']").on('change', function(){
  sortDate = $(this).val();
});
```

so then I have my click function where I need to value

```
$('.sortDates').on('click', function(){
  //Good stuff
});
```

Now, I have tried to return the value of sort date in the click function by using `return sortDate;` and then passing it into the click function, but that doesn't seem to want to work. Any help would be great!

Comment: That is not at all making sense. You should re frame your question.

Comment: You have declared `sortDate` as global. Why not using it directly within the click function? (if they all are in the same document scope)

Comment: clicking on button is alerting changed value.. http://jsfiddle.net/4W8uC/ whats the problem?

Comment: @ThinkDifferent I dont want to have the change function within the click function though because I want to use that value it returns to call a class.

Comment: @Krishna The problem is that that is not working in my jquery or else I would not be here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
$("input[name='sortField']").on('change', function(){
    sortDate = $(this).val();
    $('.sortDates').on('click', function(){
       console.log(sortDate);
    });
});
```

Also, if you have the variable declared at the top level, then it is a global variable. Why don't you use it instead?

Comment: I cant do this because I they could not change the input, but I still want them to be able to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

That `sortDate` is global and you can access  it every where. If you are looking for how to send data to an even, here you go

```
  var sortDate = 'revRec';
  $("input[name='sortField']").on('change', function(){
        sortDate = $(this).val();
   });
  $('.sortDates').bind('click',{sortDate:$("input[name='sortField']").val()}, 
   function(e){
      //Good stuff
      //return or alert e.data.sortDate;
  });
```

Comment: How would I grab the value though in the click function? I have tried console logging e.data.sortDate and sortDate, but it doent seem to return anything

Comment: Now I am getting a value by commenting out the return, but it's not changing when the value changes.

Comment: Please see my last edits... If it does not work, You'd post more html of yours in order to help us to help you.